# $U$ be open in $X$ and $A:=X \setminus U$ , is the function $f: U \to \mathbb R ; f(x):=dist (x,A) , \forall x \in U$ injective ?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a  metric space , $U$ be open in $X$ and $A:=X \setminus U$ , is the function $f: U \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x):=dist (x,A) , \forall x \in U$ injective ? If not , then do we need to assume completeness of $(X,d)$ or any other property to force injectiveness ?

Comment: Not. Take $(X,d) = (\mathbb R,$ usual distance$)$, $U = ]0,1[$. Choose the points $x = 0.25$ and $y = 0.75$.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably *not* injective: take $X = \mathbb R^2$, and $U$ the unit ball. Then $x_1 = (1/2, 0)$ and $x_2 = (-1/2, 0)$ are the same distance to $A$.